# Drill through to bookmark

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I've set a button action as `Drill through` type, and defined a `Destination` from measure.

Returning a page from the measure is fine, but I'm wondering if there is a way to return/drill through to a specific bookmark.

I created a table where first column reports the page names, second column the bookmark names and third column an ID.

I'm using the ID to direct the selection in the measure as follows:

`IF(CONTAINSSTRING(SELECTEDVALUE(DimEquip[MachSys]), "ACF"),  LOOKUPVALUE(Page_Views[View],Page_Views[ID],1),  LOOKUPVALUE(Page_Views[View],Page_Views[ID],2),`